# $.post to .aspx page from asp.net mvc page

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to route with `$.post()`  method from ASP.Net MVC page to ASPX page. Is it possible?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("document").ready(function () {
        $("#deneme").bind("click", function () {
            $.post("@Url.Content("~/Home/Rapor/")", function (data) {
            });
        });
    }); 
</script>
```

global.asax

```
routes.MapPageRoute(
    "Rapor",
    "Home/Rapor", //{gelen}/{id}",
    "~/Views/Home/WebForm1.aspx",
    true, null,
    new RouteValueDictionary { { "outgoing", new MyCustomConstaint() } }
);
```

Comment: Yes it's possible. Do you have a specific problem with this code?

Comment: When i click button it doesn't give any response.

Comment: What are you expecting to happen? There is no code in your success handler - `function(data) { /* code goes here */ }`. Also, have you checked the console to make sure there are no errors?

Comment: i want to stay when i go to .aspx page with this request so i don't use any sucesss message. but breakpoint hasn't crashed

Comment: So i want post my mvc form to aspx page these is necessary because when i try to this with response.redirect my url parameter too long.and that doesn't support for >248.i try to use this solution for this reason.

Answer (score 0):

because you are not using the response:

```
$("#deneme").bind("click", function () {
    $.post("@Url.Content("~/Home/Rapor/")", function (data) {
       alert(data);
       $('#anyDivID').html(data);
    });
});
```